# Copy global array to another global array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, structure

I have global array 'SocietyName' which is pointer by local array 'SocietyNameFinal'. Then copy local array to void 'CITY.stAREA1.pvSociety' and 'CITY.stAREA2.pvSociety'. so I can use two different copy of array for separate use. any modification in one void will not effect to another void. How can I do it?

Currently when I have first entry in 'SocietyInit' function stAREA1.pvSociety have first element as"TOM". when second entry in function stAREA2.pvSociety have first element as "JERRY" but I also notice that first element of stAREA1.pvSociety is also modify to "JERRY" (As I have use same pointer for both).
    I want first element of stAREA2.pvSociety as "TOM" and stAREA2.pvSociety as "JERRY". how can I have it??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define PERSON_NAME(sPersonName) { 0, 0, sPersonName }
#define SOCIETY_HEAD(sText)      { 0, 0, sText }

char PersonName[32] = {0};

typedef struct
{
    int SocietyNumber1;
    int SocietyNumber2;
    char const * const pszText;
} Text_st_t;

Text_st_t SocietyName[] =
{
    PERSON_NAME(PersonName),
    SOCIETY_HEAD("AMAR")        // Many other array members
};

typedef struct
{
    char szPersonName[15];
    void *pvSociety;
} AREA_st_t;

typedef struct
{
    AREA_st_t  stAREA1;
    AREA_st_t  stAREA2;
} CITY_st_t;

typedef struct
{
    CITY_st_t      CITY_stAREA;
} State_st_t;

State_st_t* STATE, sample;

#define CITY    STATE->CITY_stAREA

void SocietyInit(AREA_st_t *AREA);

int main()
{
    STATE = &sample;

    strcpy(PersonName,                  "DONAND");
    strcpy(CITY.stAREA1.szPersonName,   "TOM");
    strcpy(CITY.stAREA2.szPersonName,   "JERRY");

    SocietyInit(&(CITY.stAREA1));
    SocietyInit(&(CITY.stAREA2));

    // Here I want to First member of structe. I had tried as below but not ok. How can i do it???
    printf("stAREA1.pvSociety.szPersonName = %s\n", *((Text_st_t *)CITY.stAREA1.pvSociety));    // Here I want 'TOM'
    printf("stAREA2.pvSociety.szPersonName = %s\n", *((Text_st_t *)CITY.stAREA2.pvSociety));    // Here I want 'JERRY'

    printf("Finished");

    return 0;
}

void SocietyInit(AREA_st_t *AREA)
{
    Text_st_t *SocietyNameFinal = malloc(sizeof(SocietyName));

    (void)memcpy(SocietyNameFinal, SocietyName, sizeof(SocietyName));

    printf("===========================================\n");

    printf("SocietyName[0].pszText      = %s\n", SocietyName[0].pszText);
    printf("SocietyNameFinal[0].pszText = %s\n", SocietyNameFinal[0].pszText); 
    printf("CITY.stAREA1.szPersonName   = %s\n", CITY.stAREA1.szPersonName);
    printf("CITY.stAREA2.szPersonName   = %s\n", CITY.stAREA2.szPersonName);

    printf("-------------------------------\n");    
    strcpy((char *)SocietyNameFinal[0].pszText, AREA->szPersonName);

    printf("SocietyName[0].pszText      = %s\n", SocietyName[0].pszText);
    printf("SocietyNameFinal[0].pszText = %s\n", SocietyNameFinal[0].pszText); 
    printf("CITY.stAREA1.szPersonName   = %s\n", CITY.stAREA1.szPersonName);
    printf("CITY.stAREA2.szPersonName   = %s\n", CITY.stAREA2.szPersonName);

    printf("===========================================\n");
    AREA->pvSociety = (Text_st_t *)SocietyNameFinal;    // Copy local array to another global array

    return;
}
```

Comment: They share the same string. Either declare an array of char in the struct, or copy *each and every* string to a newly-allocated array of char (possibly with `strdup`).

Answer (score 1):

there are three ways of copying the tables.

1. iterate and copy
2. memcpy it
3. wrap into a struct and assign

   ```
   struct {
       int x[16];
   }x,y;


   void foo(void)
   {
        y=x;
   }
   ```

the last method is usually the most efficient for the small arrays (for the larger ones memcpy is often called)

https://godbolt.org/z/rO6-of

Comment: I have larger array so I have already use memcpy function if you see my code. memcpy use pointer so when I modify my array in second entry in function it also modify my previous copy. I want separate copy for both entry which not effect any modification to each other